# Image segmentation by pixel intensity in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to segment a part of an image in matlab. I'm using CT images and I would like to segment the teeth that have metal because this metal artifacts compromise the image quality. Can someone give me a help?

[image]
[image]

1. What I want to segment
                                          2. Original image

Comment: Use iterative reconstruction  algorithms for noise reduction :P

Comment: Are you trying to _find_ the tooth first (i.e. feature extraction)? Or *just* segment it? I.e. are you hoping for a fully automated approach, or are you happy to place initial markers etc?

Comment: That's **very** difficult to do just by intensity alone.  You should use the shapes or structures around what you want to segment, or give some hints on the shape of what you want to extract out as extra information.

Comment: I want to segment the tooth to try to reduce the damage made by the metal artifacts. And reconstruct the image without the "flash" caused by them.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple start, you can use a simple threshold that you set manually based on the histogram.

```
    imhist(image)
    threshold = 120
    binaryImage = image>threshold
    imshow(binaryImage)
```

next find the boundary of the binary image using some function such as `bwtraceboundary`. Finally, combine the original image and the boundary image to produce the final image.

I think the hardest part would be the threshold.